# Special LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join, left-join, impala

I have the following SQL (Impala) pseudo query, since it wont compile this way. The interesting part is the last, where I want to do exactly what you can read.

I want to do a LEFT JOIN but in case there is no matching ProductId I want to use a specific ProductId (which is NULL and suppose there is only one but guaranteeing it by using LIMIT 1) and perform a JOIN-like connection so the above conditions in the CASE-WHEN would work properly.

So basically the question is that if there is a way to transform this syntactically incorrect query to a single correct one?

I was trying different things using e.g. ISNULL() and WITH, but since the subquery which you can see in the ELSE part has to use 2 tables to work properly it can not be compiled anyway it would work in my opinion.

```
SELECT 
    cd.CycleDataId AS CycleDataId,
    CASE   
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime <= op.MaxValue THEN NVL(dcl.ProductionLossTypeId, -1)
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime >= op.MaxValue THEN dcl.ProductionLossTypeId
    END AS Verdikt,
    CASE   
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime <= op.MaxValue THEN NVL(dcl.Time, cd.CycleTime - op.IdealValue)
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime >= op.MaxValue THEN dcl.Time  
    END AS Time
FROM CycleData cd
LEFT JOIN DistributedCycleLosses dcl ON dcl.CycleDataId = cd.CycleDataId
CASE   
WHEN IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Operation_parameter WHERE ProductId = cd.ProductId AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo) THEN LEFT JOIN Operation_parameter op ON op.ProductId = cd.ProductId AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN op.ValidFrom AND op.ValidTo
ELSE (SELECT * FROM Operation_parameter WHERE ProductId IS NULL AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo LIMIT 1) AS op
END;
```

Comment: Please do not post invalid code as description, it doesn't mean anything. In particular, "if condition then join". Use words to explain. Give code that runs for relevant parts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically using a default value.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT cd.CycleDataId AS CycleDataId,
        (CASE WHEN cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue) AND 
                   cd.CycleTime <= COALESCE(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue) 
              THEN COALESCE(dcl.ProductionLossTypeId, -1)
              WHEN cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue) AND
                   COALESCE(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue)
              THEN dcl.ProductionLossTypeId
         END) AS Verdikt,
        (CASE WHEN cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue) AND
                   cd.CycleTime <= COALESCE(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue)
              THEN cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(dcl.Time, cd.CycleTime - COALESCE(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue))
              WHEN cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue) AND
                   cd.CycleTime >= COALESCE(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue)
              THEN dcl.Time  
         END) AS Time
FROM CycleData cd LEFT JOIN 
     DistributedCycleLosses dcl
     ON dcl.CycleDataId = cd.CycleDataId LEFT JOIN
     Operation_parameter op
     ON op.ProductId = cd.ProductId AND
        cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN op.ValidFrom AND op.ValidTo LEFT JOIN
     Operation_parameter opnull
     ON op.ProductId IS NULL AND  -- no previous match
        opnull.ProductID IS NULL AND
        cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN opnull.ValidFrom AND opnull.ValidTo ;
```

Note that all references to `op` are replaced with `COALESCE()` expressions.

You can modify this to handle multiple rows for matching `NULL` values, if that is really necessary.  I think the more important part of the logic are the `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: It is much better then using subquery . One small  disadvantage is two values for one field  op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue

Comment: I got this error using your exact code but managed to fix it! I had to keep the NVL-s where those were already used. Thank you!

AnalysisException: Operand 'coalesce(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue)' part of predicate 'cd.CycleTime >= coalesce(op.IdealValue, opnull.IdealValue) AND coalesce(op.MaxValue, opnull.MaxValue)' should return type 'BOOLEAN' but returns type 'INT'.

Answer (score 0):

that is a bit tricky thing to set default value for whole entity but for list of fields it might be implemented like this :

```
SELECT 
    cd.CycleDataId AS CycleDataId, ISNull(op.[parameterName],'default parameter value') as [parameterName]
    CASE   
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime <= op.MaxValue THEN NVL(dcl.ProductionLossTypeId, -1)
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime >= op.MaxValue THEN dcl.ProductionLossTypeId
    END AS Verdikt,
    CASE   
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime <= op.MaxValue THEN NVL(dcl.Time, cd.CycleTime - op.IdealValue)
        WHEN cd.CycleTime >= op.IdealValue AND cd.CycleTime >= op.MaxValue THEN dcl.Time  
    END AS Time
FROM CycleData cd
LEFT JOIN DistributedCycleLosses dcl ON dcl.CycleDataId = cd.CycleDataId,
LEFT JOIN Operation_parameter op ON op.ProductId = cd.ProductId AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN op.ValidFrom AND op.ValidTo
```

Comment: Yep, but it isn't what I am looking for. I tried IsNull(op.IdealValue, SELECT IdealValue FROM Operation_parameter WHERE ProductId IS NULL AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo LIMIT 1) and something similar but either way cd is not defined and I have to do the same LEFT JOIN and get back to the original problem or if I leave out that part using another table I get an error stating that IsNull() cant contain a subquery as a parameter. I even tried without a subquerry inside of the IsNull() but using a WITh clause outside and referenccing it but still the same JOIN problem is present.

Comment: ISNull(op.IdealValue ,(SELECT op2.IdealValue FROM Operation_parameter as op2 WHERE ProductId IS NULL AND cd.Timestamp_ BETWEEN op2.ValidFrom AND op2.ValidTo LIMIT 1)) as IdealValue - this subquery  should work  you could use values from cd table inside it

Comment: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 30:undefined: ...e >= ISNull(op.IdealValue,SELECT op2.IdealValue FROM O... ^ Encountered: SELECT Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: I have a bit adjusted subquery right now. It needs additionally round brackets near select